# How to receive uncertain numbers of return values in python

Tags: python

**Update:** I am writing a decorator of flask app. The aim of it is to wrap the response in the struct like this:

```json
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "successful",
    "data": null
}
```

And for the view function, it only needs to return the content of `data`. If some exceptions occur, the view function would to return a second value `code`.

The code snippet of the decorator:

```py
def foo():
    resp = {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "successful",
        "data": None,
    }

    data, code = func(*args, **kwargs)
    if code == 0 or not code:
        resp['data'] = data
    else:
        resp = build_exception_resp(code, data)
```

The problem is, if everything is ok, I only want to return the `data`; and only if there are something wrong, the second value `code` should be returned.

Original description:

For example:

```py
def foo():
    i = int(input())
    if i == 0:
        return 0, 0
    else:
        return 0

a, b = foo()
```

The length of return value is uncertain, and in the second case, it would throw an cannot unpack error. Are there any pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can return a list instead, or just return 0,None if the a,b = foo() syntax is required.

Comment: One quick idea would be to return 0, None instead of just 0 and afterwards do a check if b is None

Comment: Assign the return value to a single variable and then test to see what that variable holds. Unpack that variable into 2 if appropriate. But -- I agree that this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: There are ways, but it is not good programming practice to return a tuple of unknown length.

Comment: In the code as edited -- if `func` is under your control just make sure that it always returns a tuple, possibly with a `None` component. If it isn't under your control, you could assign its return value to a variable which you `try` to unpack, moving the logic that you currently have for `not code` into an `except` clause.